# How to specify an object expiration prefix that doesn't match the directory?

Tags: amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket with `img`, `mov`, and `tmp` directories. I would like everything added to `tmp` to be removed automatically once it's over three days old. So I set up [object expiration](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ObjectExpiration.html) rules on my bucket like so:

- prefix: "tmp/"
- expiration: 3

The problem is, while the files inside `tmp` are removed on schedule, `tmp` itself also matches this prefix (dispite the trailing slash) and gets deleted every three days.

Is there any prefix that will match the contents of `tmp`, but not `tmp` itself? Something like "tmp/*" (though that doesn't work)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why do you want to keep `tmp` at all?

[Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) doesn't actually have a native concept of folders/directories, rather is a flat storage architecture comprised of buckets and objects/keys only - the directory style presentation seen in most tools for S3 (including the [AWS Management Console](http://aws.amazon.com/console/) itself) is based solely on convention, i.e. simulating a hierarchy for objects with identical prefixes (e.g.`tmp/` in your case); see the respective FAQ [How is Amazon S3 data organized?](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/#How_is_Amazon_S3_data_organized):

> Amazon S3 is a simple **key-based object store**. When you store data, you
>   assign a unique object key that can later be used to retrieve the
>   data. Keys can be any string, and **can be constructed to mimic
>   hierarchical attributes.**
>
> *[emphasis mine]*

This architecture is further detailed in [Amazon S3 Concepts](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#CoreConcepts):

> **Buckets**
>
> A bucket is a container for objects stored in Amazon S3. Every object
>   is contained in a bucket. For example, if the object **named
>   photos/puppy.jpg** is stored in the johnsmith bucket, then it is
>   addressable using the URL
>   http://johnsmith.s3.amazonaws.com/photos/puppy.jpg
>
> [...]
>
> **Keys**
>
> **A key is the unique identifier for an object within a bucket.** Every
>   object in a bucket has exactly one key. Because the combination of a
>   bucket, key, and version ID uniquely identify each object, **Amazon S3
>   can be thought of as a basic data map** between "bucket + key + version"
>   and the object itself.
>
> *[emphasis mine]*

Therefore there shouldn't be any need to care about these 'directories' at all, they will just resurface any time you happen to store an object with a respective prefix in its name.

Comment: I'm assuming from your answer that what I want isn't possible? Is that correct? As to why I want it, because the people using this aren't interfacing with it via the API. They're doing so via Transmit and the management console. It's easier for me to tell them "put the files you want to expire in the `tmp` directory" than it is to say "first, create the `tmp` directory if it doesn't already exist".

Comment: @jemmons: I see, an understandable use case - unfortunately this is not possible out of the box indeed. A possible workaround might be to protect the `tmp` object from deletion by an appropriate [S3 Access Control](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingAuthAccess.html) solution, i.e either a [Bucket Policy](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucketPolicies.html) or an [IAM Policy](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingIAMPolicies.html); I'm not sure right now whether object expiration can in fact be controlled/overruled like so.

Answer (score -1):

Seems that this should be possible with IAM: You create an IAM user that can only delete files in tmp (and not tmp/ itself) then use that user to put a lifecycle on the bucket. Then the tmp/ object will not be deleted.

But the docs are not all too clear on this - you would have to test it.

Comment: This is based on a misunderstanding of how keys work, if you create `tmp/file.txt` then there is *no such object* `tmp`, therefore nothing to delete and nothing to protect.