# S3 boto list keys sometimes returns directory key

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, boto

I've noticed a difference between the returns from boto's api depending on the bucket location. I have the following code:

```
con = S3Connection(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
bucket = con.get_bucket(S3_BUCKET_NAME)
keys = bucket.list(path)
for key in keys:
  print key
```

which im running against two buckets, one in us-west and one in ireland. Path in this bucket is a sub-directory, against Ireland I get the sub directory and any keys underneath, against us-west I only get the keys beneath.

So Ireland gives:

```
<Key: <bucketName>,someDir/>
<Key: <bucketName>,someDir/someFile.jpg>
<Key: <bucketName>,someDir/someOtherFile.jpg>
```

where as US Standard gives:

```
<Key: <bucketName>,someDir/someFile.jpg>
<Key: <bucketName>,someDir/someOtherFile.jpg>
```

Obviously, I want to be able to write the same code regardless of bucket location. Anyone know of anything I can do to work around this so I get the same predictable results. Or even if it's boto causing the problem or S3. I noticed there is a different policy for naming buckets in Ireland, do different locals have their own version of the api's?

Thanks,

Steve

Comment: Not done extensive testing, but Northern California seems to do the same thing as Ireland. Not sure which is the desired result.

Comment: Good question and an annoying difference indeed - I'm pretty sure all regions but _US Standard_ will return the same result (i.e. a dedicated object/key for the simulated directory), see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9955959/45773) for details on this.

Comment: To ensure the analysis is actually digging into the correct origin: How have these buckets/keys been created in the first place? Or more specifically, have these been created by a 3rd party service/tool or by yourself via the _S3 API_ or the _AWS Management Console_?

Comment: Good point, I have keys that have been uploaded using the console, and also some created by boto. I think I will look into if they consistently behave the same way for both.

Comment: i experience the same, but with boto3, and in the context of the same AWS account, but different buckets. When listing the content of one bucket by prefix via objects.filter(), it also returns folder, but for other buckets it returns only files.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Thanks to Steffen, who suggested looking at how the keys are created. With further investigation I think I've got a handle on whats happening here. My original suposition that it was linked to the bucket region was a red herring. It appears to be due to what the management console does when you manipulate keys.

If you create a directory in the management console it creates a 0 byte key. This will be returned when you perform a list.

If you use boto to create/upload a file then it doesn't create the folder. Interestingly, if you delete the file from within the folder (from the AWS console) then a key is created for the folder that used to contain the key. If you then upload the bey again using boto, then you have exactly the same looking structure from the UI, but infact you have a spurious additional key for the directory. This is what was happening to me, as I was testing our application I was clearing out keys and then finding different results.

Worth knowing this happens. There is no indicator in the UI to show if a folder is a created one (one that will be returned as a key) or an interpreted one (based on a keys name).

Comment: +1 for following up with your analysis, thanks! Quite some confusing behind the scene magic indeed ...

Comment: The AWS console is creating an empty file named 'bucketName/someDir/' which is quite confusing; you can delete that empty "file" from the command line and then that clears up the issue

Answer (score 6):

I don't have a definite answer for your question, but can throw in some partial ones at least:

## Background

### Directory/Folder simulation

[Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) doesn't actually have a native concept of folders/directories, rather is a flat storage architecture comprised of buckets and objects/keys only - the directory style presentation seen in most tools for S3 (including the [AWS Management Console](http://aws.amazon.com/console/) itself) is based solely on convention, i.e. simulating a hierarchy for objects with identical prefixes - see my answer to [How to specify an object expiration prefix that doesn't match the directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9422742/45773) for more details on this architecture, including quotes/references from the AWS documentation.

### API differences per region

> I noticed there is a different policy for naming buckets in Ireland,
>   do different locals have their own version of the api's?

That's apparently the case indeed for [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) specifically, which is one of their oldest offerings, see e.g. [Bucket Restrictions and Limitations](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html):

> In all regions **except for the US Standard region**, You must use the
>   following guidelines when naming a bucket. [...] *[emphasis mine]*

These specifics for the *US Standard* region are seen in other places of the [S3 documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Welcome.html?r=4894) as well, and *US Standard* is an unusual construct itself compared to the otherwise clearly geographically constrained [Regions](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#Regions):

> **US Standard** — Uses Amazon S3 servers in the United States
>
> This is the default Region. **The US Standard Region automatically
>   routes requests to facilities in Northern Virginia or the Pacific
>   Northwest** using network maps. To use this region, select US Standard
>   as the region when creating a bucket in the console. The US Standard
>   Region provides eventual consistency for all requests. *[emphasis mine]*

This implicit CDN behavior is unique for this *default Region* of S3 (i.e. *US Standard*) and not seen elsewhere on any other AWS service I think.

## Likely Cause

I have a faint memory of S3 actually placing a zero byte object/key into a bucket for the simulated directory/folder in more recent regions (i.e. all but *US Standard*), whereas the legacy solution for the US Standard region might be different, for example simply based on the established naming convention for directory separation by `/` and omitting a dedicated object/key for this altogether.

### Solution

If the analysis is correct, there is nothing you can do but maintain separate code paths for both cases, I'm afraid

Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

I've had the same problem. As a work around you can filter out all the keys with a trailing `'/'` to eliminate the 'directory' entries.

```
def files(keys):
    return (key for key in keys if not key.name.endswith('/'))

s3 = boto.connect_s3(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
bucket = s3.get_bucket(S3_BUCKET_NAME)
keys = bucket.list(path)
for key in files(keys):
    print(key)
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use the size parameter to exclude the prefix:

```
for key in keys: 
  if key.size > 0:
  print key
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the fact that a "Folder" has no "." in its path.
A file does.
media/images will not be deleted
media/images/sample.jpg will be deleted

e.g. clean bucket files

```
def delete_all_bucket_files(self,bucket_name):
        bucket = self.get_bucket(bucket_name)
        if bucket:
            for key in bucket.list():
                #delete only the files, not the folders
                if period_char in key.name:
                    print 'deleting: ' + key.name
                    key.delete()
```