# Size of folder in s3 bucket

Tags: php, amazon-s3

i am working on amazon s3 bucket. And i need to find a size of the folder inside a bucket through the code. I'm not finding any method to find the size of the folder directly. So is there any other way to achieve this function?

**EDIT :** I'm aware that there is nothing called folders in s3 bucket. But i need to find the size of all files looking like a folder folder structure. That is, if the structure is like this, `https://s3.amazonaws.com/****/uploads/storeeoll48jipuvjbqufcap3p6on6er2bwsufv5ojzqnbe01xvw0fy58x65.png` then i need to find the size of all files with the structure, `https://s3.amazonaws.com/****/uploads/...`

Comment: do you mean the size of the contents of the folder?

Comment: Yes. Size of contents of all files in the folder and sub folders.

Comment: Programatically (Which language?) or using a tool (which tool?)?

Comment: Helps to put it as part of the question, tags are more for searching on, I often search the amazon-s3 tag for example but I'm not a PHP developer.  I see the marked answer user wasn't clear on what language either...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From AwsConsoleApp.java AWS SDK sample:

```
List<Bucket> buckets = s3.listBuckets();
long totalSize  = 0;
int  totalItems = 0;
for (Bucket bucket : buckets)
{
    ObjectListing objects = s3.listObjects(bucket.getName());
    do {
        for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : objects.getObjectSummaries()) {
            totalSize += objectSummary.getSize();
            totalItems++;
        }
        objects = s3.listNextBatchOfObjects(objects);
    } while (objects.isTruncated());
    System.out.println("You have " + buckets.size() + " Amazon S3 bucket(s), " +
                    "containing " + totalItems + " objects with a total size of " + totalSize + " bytes.");
}
```

Comment: Although i need a PHP code, this code gives me some idea about how to write. Thanks.

Comment: ah, sorry, didn't look at the tags :)

Answer (score 5):

if you would want to use boto in python here is a small script that you may try:

```
import boto
conn=boto.connect_s3('api_key','api_secret')
bucket=conn.get_bucket('bucketname');
keys=bucket.list('path')
size=0
for key in keys:
        size+= key.size
print size
```

Comment: I found that s3 sometimes reports folders in this listing which was causing wierd totals. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954521/s3-boto-list-keys-sometimes-returns-directory-key. I ended up filtering out the files with a trailing slash.

Answer (score 1):

here is how I did with boto3

the function that return directory (key) size in MB from bucket

```
s3_client   = client('s3')  
def get_s3_folder_size_mb(bucket,prefix):
    len = 0
    s3_result =  s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix)
    for key in s3_result['Contents']:
        len+=key['Size'] 
        while s3_result['IsTruncated']:
            continuation_key = s3_result['NextContinuationToken']
            s3_result = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix, ContinuationToken=continuation_key)
            for key in s3_result['Contents']:
                len+=key['Size']
    return len/1024/1024
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing called "folders" in an S3, it is a flat file system. The file names(bucket keys) may contain slashes (/), and various bucket explorers can use this to interpret folder-file structure.

To know the size of a "folder" in S3, you would first have to know the keys of all individual files that contain the substring of that "folder" path. If you bucket contains millions of files, this would be a very costly operation.

Some S3 explorers do that automatically. I use Cloudberry explorer for S3.

Answer (score 0):

Folders don't really exist in S3.

An object with a Key of `subfolder/myfile.txt` is displayed by the software as being in the `subfolder` folder.  But its only a display thing, the folder doesn't really exist.  If you want to find out how many items are in that 'folder' programatically, loop through all the objects that start with subfolder/ get their size and add it up.  Alternatively Check out [S3Browser](http://s3browser.com/) which gives you the size on right click.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it with boto3:

```
import boto3

bucketName = '<bucketname>'
client = boto3.client('s3')

def get_all_objects_in_prefix(prefix):
    lastkey = ''
    while True:
        response = client.list_objects(
            Bucket=bucketName,
            Prefix=prefix,
            Marker=lastkey,
            MaxKeys=1000
        )
        if not response.get('Contents'):
            break
        lastkey = [item['Key'] for item in response['Contents']][-1]
        for item in response['Contents']:
            yield item

def get_filesize_of_prefix(prefix):
    size = 0
    for item in get_all_objects_in_prefix(prefix):
        size += item['Size']

    return size
```