# Amazon S3 boto - how to delete folder?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I created a folder in s3 named "test" and I pushed "test_1.jpg", "test_2.jpg" into "test".

How can I use boto to delete folder "test"?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

There are **no** folders in S3. Instead, the keys form a flat namespace. However a key with slashes in its name shows specially in some programs, including the AWS console (see for example [Amazon S3 boto - how to create a folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939743/amazon-s3-boto-how-to-create-folder)).

Instead of deleting "a directory", you can (and have to) list files by prefix and delete. In essence:

```
for key in bucket.list(prefix='your/directory/'):
    key.delete()
```

However the other accomplished answers on this page feature more efficient approaches.

---

Notice that the prefix is just searched using dummy string search. If the prefix were <s>`your/directory`</s>, that is, without the trailing slash appended, the program would also happily delete `your/directory-that-you-wanted-to-remove-is-definitely-not-t‌​his-one`.

For more information, see [S3 boto list keys sometimes returns directory key.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954521/s3-boto-list-keys-sometimes-returns-directory-key)

Comment: How to delete the directory? If this directory will be deleted automatically when all files in this directory are deleted?

Comment: @wadehuang - could you share your code about deleting folders?

Comment: How to delete files in folder of s3 that are 2 days old in python. have this in my s3 -  bucket/1/backups/(10 files)  need to remove all files that are two days old

Answer (score 350):

Here is 2018 (almost 2019) version:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('mybucket')
bucket.objects.filter(Prefix="myprefix/").delete()
```

Comment: someone might find useful to know that bucket.objects.all().delete() empties the entire bucket without deleting it, no matter how many objects there are (i.e. it's not affected but the 1000 items limit). See: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.objects

Comment: Hi Raz this isn't working for me, I simply get empty square brackets, i.e. []

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't supports Suffix :(

Comment: The great thing is that this solution works even with more than 1000 objects

Comment: In case you need to specify an access key id and secret, the first line is:
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id=xxx, aws_secret_access_key=yyy)

Comment: @raz If possible Could you update the answer to reflect/print what is being deleted, and to exit the program if the token expires? Right now it works well but there's no way of knowing what is being deleted and what is happening as I only get a blinking cursor

Comment: @Soyf - i'm getting the same, and nothing is deleted.  what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can we use wild card characters in filter expression? 
```bucket.objects.filter(Prefix="2021*/").delete()```
or will have to use aws wrangler for it?

Answer (score 59):

I feel that it's been a while and boto3 has a few different ways of accomplishing this goal. This assumes you want to delete the **test** "folder" and all of its objects Here is one way:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
objects_to_delete = s3.meta.client.list_objects(Bucket="MyBucket", Prefix="myfolder/test/")

delete_keys = {'Objects' : []}
delete_keys['Objects'] = [{'Key' : k} for k in [obj['Key'] for obj in objects_to_delete.get('Contents', [])]]

s3.meta.client.delete_objects(Bucket="MyBucket", Delete=delete_keys)
```

This should make two requests, one to fetch the objects in the folder, the second to delete all objects in said folder.

https://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.delete_objects

Comment: This is the fastest solution, but keep in mind that `list_objects` can't return more than 1000 keys so you need to run this code multiple times.

Comment: You can use paginator if you have more than 1k objects - see my answer below.

Comment: @deepelement, and it only works in `boto3`, not boto

Comment: This works great, and you can run it from a Python lambda by putting the code above in a lambda_handler function: `import boto3; def lambda_handler(event, context): '''Code from above'''`. Make sure you give your Lambda permission to delete from S3 and extend the timeout.

Answer (score 31):

A slight improvement on Patrick's solution. As you might know, both `list_objects()` and `delete_objects()` have an object limit of 1000. This is why you have to paginate listing and delete in chunks. This is pretty universal and you can give `Prefix` to `paginator.paginate()` to delete subdirectories/paths

```
client = boto3.client('s3', **credentials)
paginator = client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
pages = paginator.paginate(Bucket=self.bucket_name)

delete_us = dict(Objects=[])
for item in pages.search('Contents'):
    delete_us['Objects'].append(dict(Key=item['Key']))

    # flush once aws limit reached
    if len(delete_us['Objects']) >= 1000:
        client.delete_objects(Bucket=bucket, Delete=delete_us)
        delete_us = dict(Objects=[])

# flush rest
if len(delete_us['Objects']):
    client.delete_objects(Bucket=bucket, Delete=delete_us)
```

Comment: And if you want to limit to a "directory" use the `Prefix` keyword in `paginator.paginate()` See all options: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Paginator.ListObjectsV2.paginate

Comment: with the `Prefix` filter suggested by **@Chad**, I had to add a `if item is not None` check before deletion (since some of my S3 prefixes did not exist / had no objects)

Comment: @dmitraybelyakov, when i run the above code I am getting  Typeerror: 'NoneType' object is not scbscriptable on  the follwong line delete_us['Objects'].append(dict(key=item['Key']))  would you know any reason why it would do that

Comment: @Aaron perhaps some things have changed, but try suggestion above by y2k-shubham

Comment: Works like a charm!
P.S- Don't forget to add Prefix as mentioned above.

Answer (score 24):

You can use [bucket.delete_keys()](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.bucket.Bucket.delete_keys) with a list of keys (with a large number of keys I found this to be an order of magnitude faster than using key.delete).

Something like this:

```
delete_key_list = []
for key in bucket.list(prefix='/your/directory/'):
    delete_key_list.append(key)
    if len(delete_key_list) > 100:
        bucket.delete_keys(delete_key_list)
        delete_key_list = []

if len(delete_key_list) > 0:
    bucket.delete_keys(delete_key_list)
```

Answer (score 9):

If versioning is enabled on the S3 bucket:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('mybucket')
bucket.object_versions.filter(Prefix="myprefix/").delete()
```

Comment: Is there a way to print someouput of what is being deleted? I want to delete the versions first and then the current one. ex  bucket.objects.filter(Prefix="myprefix/").delete()  ; right now I only see a blinking cursor and I don't know what is happening.

Comment: You would have to do something like `files_to_delete = bucket.object_versions.filter(Prefix="myprefix/")` then iterate over `files_to_delete` and call print() then delete() on them.

Answer (score 3):

If one needs to filter by object contents like I did, the following is a blueprint for your logic:

```py
def get_s3_objects_batches(s3: S3Client, **base_kwargs):
    kwargs = dict(MaxKeys=1000, **base_kwargs)
    while True:
        response = s3.list_objects_v2(**kwargs)
        # to yield each and every file: yield from response.get('Contents', [])
        yield response.get('Contents', [])
        if not response.get('IsTruncated'):  # At the end of the list?
            break
        continuation_token = response.get('NextContinuationToken')
        kwargs['ContinuationToken'] = continuation_token


def your_filter(b):
   raise NotImplementedError()


session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name=profile_name)
s3client = session.client('s3')
for batch in get_s3_objects_batches(s3client, Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix=prefix):
    to_delete = [{'Key': obj['Key']} for obj in batch if your_filter(obj)]
    if to_delete:
        s3client.delete_objects(Bucket=bucket_name, Delete={'Objects': to_delete})
```

Answer (score 0):

#Deleting a Files Inside Folder S3 using boto3#

```
def delete_from_minio():
    """
    This function is used to delete files or folder inside the another Folder
    """
    try:
        logger.info("Deleting from minio")
        aws_access_key_id='Your_aws_acess_key'
        aws_secret_access_key = 'Your_aws_Secret_key'
        host = 'your_aws_endpoint'
        s3 = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
                            aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key ,
                            config=boto3.session.Config(signature_version='your_version'),
                            region_name="your_region",
                            endpoint_url=host ,
                            verify=False)
        bucket = s3.Bucket('Your_bucket_name')
        for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='Directory/Sub_Directory'):
            s3.Object(bucket.name, obj.key).delete()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error Occurred while deleting from the S3,{str(e)}")
```

Hope this Helps :)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone like me wanted  a one-liner, You can also use **s3fs**.

Once you have created a **S3FileSystem** instance you can use delete with recursive.
Ex :

```
s3 = S3FileSystem(anon=True)
s3.delete("path/to/my/folder", recursive=True)
```