# How to check give directory or folder exist in given s3 bucket and if exist how to delete the folder from s3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto, boto3

I want to check whether folder or directory exist in give s3 bucket, if exist i want delete folder from s3 bucket using python code.

example for : `s3:/bucket124/test`

Here "`bucket124`" is bucket and "test" is folder contains some files like `test.txt test1.txt`

I want to delete folder "`test`" from my s3 bucket.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did it fail?

Comment: import boto3
from botocore.errorfactory import ClientError
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection, Bucket, Key

s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id='AKIA', aws_secret_access_key='vfEn')
try:
    bucket = Bucket('AKIA', 'vfEn')
    s3.head_object(Bucket='bucket124', Key='test')
    k = boto3.Key(bucket =bucket124, name='test')
    k.delete()
except ClientError:
   print("file not found")

Comment: I tried above code

Comment: edit it into your question. make life easy for those trying to help you if you want actual help

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you will do that,

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket=s3.Bucket('mausamrest');
obj = s3.Object('mausamrest','test/hello')
counter=0

for key in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='test/hello/'):
    counter=counter+1

if(counter!=0):
    obj.delete()
print(counter)
```

**mausamrest** is the bucket and **test/hello/** is the directory you want to check for items , but take care of one thing  that after checking you have to delete **test/hello** instead of *test/hello/* to delete a particular sub folder and hence the keyname in 5th line is **test/hello**

Comment: Consider renaming `obj` of `for`-loop to something else to avoid *confusion*. Are you sure that this method won't be plagued by the issue described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11427712/3679900) (i.e. paths like `test/hello-this-should-not-have-been-deleted/` also get deleted)?