# Amazon S3 delete sub-folder recursively

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, boto3

I have a S3 bucket with nested folder and file-structures. I understand that S3 has a flat concept but bear with me as I state my problem clearly.

I'd like to do this:

```
delete bucket/do-not-delete-folder/delete-this-folder-recursively
```

I've already poured over the S3 docs and followed the answers given on [python - Amazon S3 boto - how to delete folder? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426560/amazon-s3-boto-how-to-delete-folder).

I've tried two different solutions and they produce two different outputs, you guessed it right, none of them doing the thing I want it to do.

**Function 1:**

This deletes the "do-not-delete-folder" and all its contents recursively. I only want it to delete the sub-folder and not the top-level folder.

I call this with the following params:

```
DeleteAWSBucketObjects(my-bucket, do-not-delete-folder/delete-this-folder/)
```

The function is:

```
def DeleteAWSBucketObjects(bucketName, prefixStr):

    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    bucket = s3.Bucket(bucketName)

    try:
        client = boto3.client('s3')
        response = client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucketName, Prefix=prefixStr)
        if 'Contents' in response:
            for item in response['Contents']:
                while response['KeyCount'] == 1000:
                    response = client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucketName,
                                StartAfter=response['Contents'][0]['Key'],)
                    for item in response['Contents']:
                        client.delete_object(Bucket=bucketName, Key=item['Key'])
    except ClientError as e:
        error_code = int(e.response['Error']['Code'])
        print ("DeleteAWSBucketObjects : hit an exception")
        print (error_code)

    return
```

**Function 2:**

Taken from the link mentioned above. I call it with the same params as mentioned above.

Strangely enough, this results in an `Access-denied` error. I'm running it from within the same code-file in Lambda and same AWS accounts, so I'm not sure why one version of the function deletes everything and the other does not have the access to delete anything.

```
DeleteAWSBucketObjectsV2(my-bucket, do-not-delete-folder/delete-this-folder/)
```

Function:

```
def DeleteAWSBucketObjectsV2(bucketName, prefixStr):

    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    bucket = s3.Bucket(bucketName)
    objects_to_delete = s3.meta.client.list_objects(Bucket=bucketName, Prefix=prefixStr)

    delete_keys = {'Objects' : []}
    delete_keys['Objects'] = [{'Key' : k} for k in [obj['Key'] for obj in objects_to_delete.get('Contents', [])]]
    for i in delete_key:
        print("delete_key_array !!!")
        print(str(i))
    try:
        s3.meta.client.delete_objects(Bucket="MyBucket", Delete=delete_keys)
    except ClientError as e:
        error_code = int(e.response['Error']['Code'])
        print ("DeleteAWSBucketObjects : hit an exception")
        print (error_code)
```

Comment: Instead of a Python function, you could use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/). This command would do it for you: `aws s3 rm s3://MyBucket/do-not-delete-folder/delete-this-folder/ --recursive`

Answer (score 0):

What i understand from your question is , you want to delete your sub folder  named **delete-this-folder**, so here is an easy way to do so :

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket=s3.Bucket('mausamrest');
obj = s3.Object('mausamrest','do-not-delete-folder/delete-this-folder/')
counter=-1


for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='do-not-delete-folder/delete-this-folder/'):
    print(obj.key)
    try:
        obj.delete()
        counter=counter+1
    except:
        print("error occurred while deleting")

if(counter==-1):
    print("subfolder doesn't exists")
if(counter!=-1):
    print("1 subfolder and "+str(counter)+" items in it deleted")
```

here **mausamrest** is the bucketname and **do-not-delete-folder/delete-this-folder/** is the sub directories