# How to delete files that matches a specific pattern in S3 bucket?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, boto

I have an S3 bucket that I'm saving CSV files for loading them into Redshift. I'm using **Python** and **Boto3** for this. After loading them into Redshift I want to delete specific files that match a pattern that contains the processing ID for my code.

I'm saving my files into S3 bucket as follows

```
Redshift{processingID}-table1.csv
Redshift{processingID}-table2.csv
Redshift{processingID}-table3.csv
Redshift{processingID}-table4.csv
```

After processing those files that contains specific ID, I want to delete the processed files from my **S3 bucket**. How do I specify the pattern.

This is the pattern that I'm trying to delete the files from bucket.

`Redshift11-*.csv`. Here **11** is the **processingID**. How do I delete all the files that matches the pattern using **boto3**?

I've come across this.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53836093/4626254

But it seems like it is searching for the folder as prefix and not the exact pattern of the file.

Comment: What's the pattern? is it always located under the same folder?

Comment: Yes. The files will always be in root directory in the bucket.

Comment: than the Prefix trick you pointed should work. `Prefix (string) -- Limits the response to keys that begin with the specified prefix.` Since your files always under the root folder, this should work. give it a try and let us know.

Comment: Sure @Amit. Will let you know. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can do prefix filtering server-side but you'll have to do suffix-filtering client-side. For example:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

bucket = s3.Bucket('mybucket')
files = [os.key for os in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix="myfolder/Redshift11-")]
csv_files = [file for file in files if file.endswith('.csv')]

print(f'All files: {files}')
print(f'CSV files: {csv_files}')
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to tell S3 to delete files that meet a specific pattern - you just have to delete one file at a time. You can list keys with a specific prefix

**ex:** `Redshift` or `application_name_used_as_prefix`) by modifying your file naming to have a unique prefix.

Or if you need to rely on regex, then you must specify start and end rules like:

```
import re

pattern = r"Redshift([0-9]+)-(\w+).csv$"
re.match(pattern, 'Redshift2-table1.csv')
```

Hope this helps!