# How to remove all files from Linode S3 boto using python?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

I successfully create files in bucket of object storage in Linode. But while deleting all files in that storage it prompts an error.

```
import boto3
cfg = {
    "aws_access_key_id":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "aws_secret_access_key": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "endpoint_url": "*********************",
}

S3_BUCKET = "test"

# empty existing bucket
def empty_s3_bucket():
  client = boto3.client(
    's3',
    **cfg,
  )
  response = client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=S3_BUCKET)
  if 'Contents' in response:
    for item in response['Contents']:
      print('deleting file', item['Key'])
      client.delete_object(Bucket=S3_BUCKET, Key=item['Key'])
      while response['KeyCount'] == 1000:
        response = client.list_objects_v2(
          Bucket=S3_BUCKET,
          StartAfter=response['Contents'][0]['Key'],
        )
        for item in response['Contents']:
          print('deleting file', item['Key'])
          client.delete_object(Bucket=S3_BUCKET, Key=item['Key'])

empty_s3_bucket()
```

Above code cannot delete all files in that object storage however can delete single file by using different logic. Following error generates on above code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/********/linode_empty.py", line 30, in <module>
    empty_s3_bucket()
  File "c:/*********/linode_empty.py", line 16, in empty_s3_bucket
    response = client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=S3_BUCKET)        
  File "C:\********\venv\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 357, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "C:\*******\venv\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 676, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.errorfactory.NoSuchKey: An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Unknown
```

I tried for different codes suggested in old post about this on stackoverflow [Amazon S3 boto - how to delete folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426560/amazon-s3-boto-how-to-delete-folder?fbclid=IwAR0-78RHG90CR48K0k1BuL-Dq0u9IvtaHUwMnaOQ5B9aAuuGM-qEwjHqBoo) but got same error.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the previous code for less than 1000 objects

```py
import boto3
linode_obj_config = {
    "aws_access_key_id": "",
    "aws_secret_access_key": "",
    "endpoint_url": "",
}
client = boto3.client("s3", **linode_obj_config)
def get_list_of_keys_from_prefix(bucket, prefix):
    keys_list = []
    response = client.list_objects(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix)
        for obj in response['Contents']:
             keys_list.append(obj["Key"])
             # print(keys_list)
         # print('total keys in bucket: ', len(keys_list))
         # print("list keys: ", keys_list)
        return keys_list
bucket = ''
prefix = ''
keys_list = get_list_of_keys_from_prefix(bucket, prefix)
for b in keys_list:
     client.delete_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=b)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

try this:
it'll collect all the keys and batch delete 1000 at a time

```
import math
s3sr = boto3.resource('s3')
s3sc = boto3.client('s3')

def get_list_of_keys_from_prefix(bucket, prefix):
    """gets list of keys for given bucket and prefix"""
    keys_list = []
    paginator = s3sr.meta.client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
    # use Delimiter to limit search to that level of hierarchy
    for page in paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix, Delimiter='/'):
        keys = [content['Key'] for content in page.get('Contents')]
        # print('keys in page: ', len(keys))
        keys_list.extend(keys)
        # print(keys_list)
    print('total keys in bucket: ', len(keys_list))
    return keys_list

bucket = 'test'
prefix = '' #if you have 'subfolders' enter the prefix, otherwise use ''

keys_list = get_list_of_keys_from_prefix(bucket, prefix)
# print(keys_list)

total_keys = len(keys_list)
chunk_size = 1000
num_batches = math.ceil(total_keys / chunk_size) 



for b in range(0, num_batches):
    batch_to_delete = []
    for k in keys_list[chunk_size*b:chunk_size*b+chunk_size]:
        batch_to_delete.append({'Key': k})
        # print({'Key': k})
    # print(batch_to_delete)
    s3sc.delete_objects(Bucket=bucket,  Delete={'Objects': batch_to_delete,},'Quiet': True)
```