# Python way of setting a s3 subdirectory path and deleting it using boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have a path like below:

```
s3://edl-landing/lu/hello2/
```

Under which I have two tables as shown below:

[image: Path]
Now, each table has `parquet` data in the below folders format:

[image: format]

Now, I want to delete the data for `10th and 11th November`. So, below is my python code using the `boto` client but it doesn't delete the objects from `S3`. I don't get any errors. Also, I tried various solutions from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426560/amazon-s3-boto-how-to-delete-folder) but it also doesn't delete the actual data from S3.

```
prefix = "lu/hello2/"
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket(name="edl-landing")
FilesNotFound = True
blankList=[]
for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=prefix):
     #print(obj.key)
     blankList.append(obj.key.split('/')[2])
blankList = set(blankList) // 2 names
while ("" in blankList):
  blankList.remove("")
datesList = ['2020-11-10','2020-11-11']
for i in blankList:
  for j in datesList:
    path = "s3://edl-landing/lu/hello2/"+i+"/edl_load_ts="+j+"/"
    print(path)
    bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=path).delete()
    print("All the objects have been deleted for the mentioned dates...")
```

Where am I going wrong? I am running it via an EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a complete S3 URI to `bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=path)`.

This function requires an S3 object prefix, not an S3 URI.

You should have been able to verify that your code was attempting to delete zero objects because `bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=path)` returned zero objects.

Pass the relevant prefix: `"lu/hello2/"+i+"/edl_load_ts="+j+"/"`

Comment: Okay let me try it. Actually I am new to AWS concepts so wasn't aware about this

Comment: No problem. Looks like you got the prefix correct in your earlier call to `bucket.objects.filter()`.

Comment: Yeah the path which I passed is correct. So what should I pass? The path variable or the one which you suggested?

Comment: Pass the correct S3 key prefix. It appears to be `"lu/hello2/"+i+"/edl_load_ts="+j+"/"`