# Delete subfolder within S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a subfolder that I want to delete from an S3 bucket.

I want to delete the subfolder **folder2**

**mybucket/folder1/folder2/folder3**

The name of folder2 will vary, so I'm trying to loop through the objects in folder1 and somehow delete the second level folder. The current code I have works ONLY if the folder3 (subfolder of folder2) doesn't exist.

```
bucket = s3.Bucket(mybucket)
result = client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=mybucket, Delimiter='/', Prefix="folder1/")
for object in result.get('CommonPrefixes'):
    subfolder = object.get('Prefix')
    s3.Object(mybucket,subfolder).delete()
```

Comment: How about : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426560/amazon-s3-boto-how-to-delete-folder that uses filter() and prefix?

Answer (score 3):

The thing you have to remember about Amazon S3 is that folders, in the sense you think of them, don't exist. They're not real. S3 is *object storage*, which means it thinks in *objects*, not *files*. The fact that the console renders things that look like filepaths with subfolders and so forth is just for convenience.

So instead of trying to delete a folder, you want to delete all files whose names begin with that prefix.